# Does golang S3 client library has the get Iterator function to retrieve all the objects in S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3, go

I am trying to use Golang to list all the objects in S3 Bucket, however, I found the Golang

S3 List function would return only 1000 objects.

So, in PHP, I can use

$objects=S3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucket,'Prefix'=>'test/'));

which can return the next 100x objects if I iterate the 100X items in $objects. So is there any

mechanism (or iterator function) in Golang that I can also iterate the next 1000 objects from

the iterator?

Thanks

Comment: which s3 library are you using? You typically just request a max number of results, then continue where you left off on the next call.

Comment: would be https://godoc.org/launchpad.net/goamz/s3#Bucket.List. I am not  so sure how to continue from the left off on the next call. Can I have some example? Thanks so much.

Comment: from the docs you linked: `The marker parameter specifies the key to start with when listing objects in a bucket`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Yes, they do.

```
var (
    sqsRegion string
)

func init() {
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file: %s", err.Error())
    }

    sqsRegion = os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")
}

func main() {

    sess := session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(sqsRegion)})

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    resp, err := svc.ListObjects(&s3.ListObjectsInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("yourbucket"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }

    for _, key := range resp.Contents {
        log.Println(*key.Key)
    }

}
```

Comment: This will only give you 1000 entries at most. The version to iterate over all keys needs to use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#example_S3_ListObjectsV2Pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination to list all bucket's files.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

// Lists all objects in a bucket using pagination
//
// Usage:
// listObjects <bucket>
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("you must specify a bucket")
        return
    }

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    i := 0
    err := svc.ListObjectsPages(&s3.ListObjectsInput{
        Bucket: &os.Args[1],
    }, func(p *s3.ListObjectsOutput, last bool) (shouldContinue bool) {
        fmt.Println("Page,", i)
        i++

        for _, obj := range p.Contents {
            fmt.Println("Object:", *obj.Key)
        }
        return true
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to list objects", err)
        return
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/service/s3/listObjects/listObjects.go